# Action listener for select's once form is reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a server form with input, select & radio, and it occasionally need to be reset, so I'm using the jQuery function `.trigger('reset')` and this works great except I can't seem to have an action triggered once that happens. e.g. `.on("reset")` or `.on("change")` on my `<select>'s`.

Have a look at the example bellow; click on a select field and chose something, then input a name and click reset, the value are reset but, the actions `reset` or `change` are not called on the `<select>'s`.

```js
$('select[name="opt"]').on("click reset change",function(){
  
  var selected = $(this).val();

  $(".jobs>div").hide();       // Hide all jobs first.
  $(".jobs>."+selected).show(); // Show selected job.

});

$(".reset").on("click",function(){
  $('form.theff').trigger("reset");
});
```

```css
.theff * {
  display:block;
  margin:10px;
}

.jobs>div {
  display:none;
  background:gray;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="theff">
  
    <input placeholder="Your name..">
    
    <select name="opt">
        <option selected>Select Job</option>
        <option value="banker">Banker</option>
        <option value="programmer">Programmer</option>
    </select>
  
    <div class="jobs">
      <div class="banker">
         Really? a banker?
      </div>
      <div class="programmer">
         Great, your a programmer!
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <button>Submit</button>
    <a href="#" class="reset">Reset</a>

</form>
```

Comment: Please don't pluralize with apostrophes.

Comment: @James What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is not the select, triggering reset on the form wouldn't trigger an event handler set to a completely different element.

You probably want to do

```
$(".reset").on("click",function(){
    $('form.theff').get(0).reset();
    $('select[name="opt"]').trigger('change');
});
```